# Winter 2015 = winter 2014-2015 or winter 2015-2016?

Tags: dates

Does winter 2015 designate winter 2014-2015 or winter 2015-2016? Or is it ambiguous?

Example 1:

[image]

Example 2: http://huwisu.de/courses/winter/ :

> HUWISU Winter Courses 2017

Example 3: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_Fresh:_The_Hits_of_Winter_2001

> So Fresh: The Hits of Winter 2001 is a compilation of songs that were popular in Australia in winter 2001.

Example 4: http://www.fpri.org/issues/orbis-winter-2001/

> Editor’s Column Winter 2001

Comment: What is the context? It is ambiguous otherwise, but usually I would interpret it as the winter of 2014–15, e.g. for ski seasons, because most of the winter is in the new year, and a "winter quarter" is usually the first quarter of the year.

Comment: Can you give an actual usage example, where there is no other context to determine the included years?

Comment: Interesting. I'm used to the academic system. Winter 2015 or the winter quarter would be winter 2015-2016. I'm guessing "winter 2015" doesn't have a fixed meaning. Wikipedia and the National Weather Channel use two years: Winter 2015-2016.

Comment: @Max What institution? The ones I'm familiar with run fall (late September through December), winter (January through March), and spring (April through June), so in the 2015–16 academic year, the quarter is winter 2016.

Comment: @choster You know what, I might be misremembering. I went to a semester school, so we had fall, spring, and summer, no winter anything haha.

Comment: @choster e.g. X took place during winter 2015.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt But where? What kind of publication? By what kind of author? About what kind of subject?

Comment: @choster I have seen "Winter 20XX" in various contexts. Does the meaning depends on the context?

Comment: @choster I added some examples.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Yes, it depends on X. For example, the [2014 Winter Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014_Winter_Olympics). If you had examples from the beginning, include them in the post.

Comment: @choster I guess this means it is ambiguous then, if we have to do case-by-case?

Comment: Example 4, Winter 2001 = Winter 2000 -2001 (http://www.fpri.org/orbis/issues/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Winter 2015* is ambiguous and could designate both winter 2014-2015 and winter 2015-2016, although generally, and given no further context, I would assume it refers to the winter months beginning in late 2015 and ending early 2016.

But be careful. I live in the northern hemisphere. For those living in the southern hemisphere, winter falls in the middle of the year, some time between June to September.

Looking at a couple of your examples:

- [HUWISU Winter Courses 2017](http://huwisu.de/courses/winter/) begin January 2017 (northern hemisphere)
- The [*So Fresh: The Hits of Winter 2001* compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_Fresh:_The_Hits_of_Winter_2001) of songs that were popular in Australia in winter 2001 was released on 18th June 2001 (southern hemisphere)

Answer (score 2):

Winter is an odd *season* since its weather spans calendar years.

Winter time in 2015 would include the months of January, February, and December for the calendar year in 2015, based on the alignment of Memorial Day being the beginning of Summer (June, July, August) and Labor Day being the beginning of Fall (September, October, November).

However, *Winter* is a season.

From my experience (and possible bias), Winter 2015 refers to December 2015, January and February 2016. **Christmas and school holidays being the anchor for what is "Winter"**.
Often, "January" and "February" in the Winter season gets referred to by name: January 2016 (Winter 2015).